# camel sql-stored java, cannot enter array as an input parameter for oracle stored-procedure

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, apache-camel

how to use camel route to enter array as input parameter of oracle stored procedure

- database: Oracle XE 11G, table: hr.DEPARTMENTS
  example pl/sql, 
  sending departments_name in array {"Administration","Marketing"}
  expect to get sum of departments_id.

1) create a nested table type:

```
create or replace TYPE "NAME_TYPE" IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000)
```

2) create a stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE    test_departments_array
  (  p_dep_names   IN NAME_TYPE,
    r_dep_id_sum OUT INTEGER )
AS
r_dep_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
r_dep_id_sum :=0;
FOR i IN p_dep_names.first .. p_dep_names.last 
LOOP
    select d.department_id into r_dep_id 
    from hr.departments d where d.department_name=p_dep_names(i);

    r_dep_id_sum := r_dep_id_sum + r_dep_id;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('input:'||p_dep_names(i));

END LOOP;

END test_departments_array;
```

3) client code: (to prove the procedure works)

```
declare
in_values NAME_TYPE := NAME_TYPE('Administration','Marketing');
out_value INTEGER;
begin

hr.test_departments_array(
  p_dep_names => in_values,r_dep_id_sum => out_value);

DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('output:'||out_value);

end;
```

4) output:

input:Administration

input:Marketing

output:30

5) java code:

```
package test.camel.javadsl;

import java.sql.Array;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection;


@Component

public class JavaDslRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

@Autowired

DataSource dataSource;

@Override

public void configure() throws Exception {

final OracleConnection conn= (OracleConnection)dataSource.getConnection();

String[] values = {"Administration0","Marketing"};

Array array = conn.createOracleArray("NAME_TYPE", values);;

from("stream:in?promptMessage=Enter to start:")

.setHeader("p_dep_names",simple( "${array}"))

.to("sql-stored:QUERY_DEPARTMENTS_ARRAY(ARRAY ${header.p_dep_names})");

}

}
```

6) error message:

> org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-lenovo1-vb-local-1561605833377-0-1]
>   at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1846) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.createExpression(SimpleBuilder.java:117) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.evaluate(SimpleBuilder.java:90) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.SetHeaderProcessor.process(SetHeaderProcessor.java:52) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) [camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.component.stream.StreamConsumer.processLine(StreamConsumer.java:252) [camel-stream-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.component.stream.StreamConsumer.readFromStream(StreamConsumer.java:216) [camel-stream-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.component.stream.StreamConsumer.run(StreamConsumer.java:120) [camel-stream-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_191]
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_191]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
>
> Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleIllegalSyntaxException: Unknown function: array at location 0
>   ${array}
>   *
>   at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.parseExpression(SimpleExpressionParser.java:67) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleLanguage.createExpression(SimpleLanguage.java:186) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleLanguage.createExpression(SimpleLanguage.java:220) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.builder.SimpleBuilder.createExpression(SimpleBuilder.java:115) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   ... 14 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleParserException: Unknown function: array
>   at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression.createSimpleExpression(SimpleFunctionExpression.java:256) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionExpression.createExpression(SimpleFunctionExpression.java:58) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart.doCreateLiteralExpression(SimpleFunctionStart.java:68) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.language.simple.ast.SimpleFunctionStart.createExpression(SimpleFunctionStart.java:58) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.createExpressions(SimpleExpressionParser.java:174) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.doParseExpression(SimpleExpressionParser.java:97) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   at org.apache.camel.language.simple.SimpleExpressionParser.parseExpression(SimpleExpressionParser.java:64) ~[camel-core-2.22.5.jar:2.22.5]
>   ... 17 common frames omitted

Comment: This is not how simple language works. What about `.setHeader("p_dep_names",constant(array))`?

Comment: thanks for Bedla's suggestion.

Comment: I am not a frequent editor, don't understand why get a down-vote. maybe the description that show my research effort is too long? so the question I listed in first line is not clear? Too bad I cannot edit my question now.

Comment: I have downvoted this, because the question was poorly formatted and was hard to read. Now, after edit by a_horse_with_now_name it is fine and I have removed downvote

Comment: thanks for the reformatting

Answer (score 1):

I have to made the following changes to make it work. Thanks for Bedla.

```
ARRAY array = (ARRAY) conn.createOracleArray("NAME_TYPE", values);

from("timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&delay=1000")
    .setHeader("p_dep_names", constant(array)) // Used constant to pass array reference instead of simple
    .to("sql-stored:TEST_DEPARTMENTS_ARRAY(ARRAY 'NAME_TYPE' ${header.p_dep_names}, OUT INTEGER r_dep_id_sum )") // Used 'NAME_TYPE'
    .to("log:stream");
```

Comment: if use process(), I have to do the following             .process(new Processor() {
   @Override
   public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
   String[] values = {"Administration0","Marketing"}; 
   ARRAY array = (ARRAY) conn.createOracleArray("NAME_TYPE", values);   
         exchange.getIn().setBody(array);
  }})
  .setHeader("p_dep_names",simple("${body}"))